# How to inject bean inside for loop with parameters

Tags: java, cdi, javabeans, java-ee-8

Can I inject Beans with parameters inside the for loop?
I don't want to initialize manually `TheService` how in the following example:

```
@Singelton
public class Scheduler {
    @Inject
    private UserQueryService userQueryService;

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/30", persistent = false)
    public void execute() {
        final List<User> users = userQueryService.findAll();
        for (final User user : users) {
            final TheService service = new TheService(user.getName(), user.getAge());
            service.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible for example runtime inject values from for loop to producer's method and inject service with CDI? I know, that String and primitive values cannot be injected, but maybe you can help me and suggest some solution.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class TheServiceFactory {
    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public TheService createTheService(final String name, final int age) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Update:**
`TheService` has other fields with `@Inject` annotations.

Comment: Why don't you want to inject `TheService` into the class? As a service, it's going to be a stateless singleton, right?

Comment: @RobertBain sorry, I forgot to note, that ```TheService``` has other fields with ```@Inject``` annotations.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're trying to do.

At any given moment, you want to get a snapshot of all `User`s in the system.  Then, for each one, you want there to exist a `RequestScoped` `TheService`, which will then be used to do something.

As written, this isn't really possible with CDI.

I'm assuming you want to produce a `TheService` instance and use CDI's dependency mechanism because `TheService` has some `@Inject`-annotated fields?  I am just guessing.

If so, you can fake it somewhat like this:

```java
final Unmanaged<TheService> unmanagedService = new Unmanaged<TheService>(TheService.class);
final UnmanagedInstance<TheService> serviceInstance = unmanagedService.newInstance();
final TheService service = serviceInstance.produce().inject().postConstruct().get();
// Any @Inject-annotated fields in service will now be "filled" if possible; that's
// what the inject() call above does; any @PostConstruct methods it has will have been
// invoked, etc.
// You'll have to manually set its user and age properties:
service.setUser(user.getName());
service.setAge(user.getAge());
service.doSomething();
// The TheService instance is NOT in request scope; *you* are fully in control
// of its lifecycle, so don't forget to dispose it when you're done.  You may
// need to put this in a finally block to ensure it happens:
serviceInstance.preDestroy().dispose();
```

CDI beans are "static" by design.  What you want to do is dynamic, i.e. it changes at runtime (maybe the query service returns totally different `User` instances when it's called each time).  So injecting a fully-managed `TheService` isn't really what you want to do since you can't predict how many of them there will be or how they will be built.

The `Unmanaged` construct in CDI is for when you want to manage the *lifespan* of something that would otherwise be a CDI bean yourself.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes, you are right. I forgot to write, that ```TheService``` has other fields with ```@Inject``` annotation.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  Kindly consider accepting it if so.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively `TheService` has a `doSomething()` method that acts on a user name and age. `TheService` has other dependencies too (`@Inject`ed fields/constructor arguments).

Why don't you make this explicit by making `TheService` `@ApplicationScoped` and defining the arguments on `doSomething()`, i.e.:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class TheService {
    @Inject DependencyOne dependencyOne;
    @Inject DependencyTwo dependencyTwo;

    public void doSomething(String userName, int age) {
        // use dependencies
    }
}
```

If `doSomething()` actually needs to keep state for each loop iteration, e.g. what you really want is:

```
@Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/30", persistent = false)
public void execute() {
    final List<User> users = userQueryService.findAll();
    for (final User user : users) {
        final TheService service = new TheService(user.getName(), user.getAge());
        service.doSomething();
        // ...
        service.doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Then you could encapsulate the state per iteration in another object, e.g. (assuming Java >= 8):

```
// TheServiceWorker.java
public interface TheServiceWorker {
    void doSomething();
    void doSomethingElse();
}

// TheService.java
@ApplicationScoped
public class TheService {
    @Inject DependencyOne dependencyOne;
    @Inject DependencyTwo dependencyTwo;

    public TheServiceWorker makeWorker(String userName, int age) {
        return new TheServiceWorker() {
            public void doSomething() {
                // you can access dependencyOne, dependencyTwo
                // AND userName, age here!
            }

            public void doSomethingElse() {
                // you can access dependencyOne, dependencyTwo
                // AND userName, age here!
            }
        };
    }
}
```